# separate JSON response data and replace some html tag

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I want to retrieve data from database and it's display in the div tag with separate line .

This is my data in database

- column name - prod_desc
- data - Camera :25MP | Memory :32GB | Battery: 3400mAh | Ram : 3GB
- data type - varchar

I want to display like this

- Camera :25MP
- Memory :32GB
- Battery: 3400mAh
- Ram : 3GB

```js
     var prodid =  $("#prod_id").val();
     var url = "lib/function.php?type=getProductDetails";
    
     $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        url:url,
        data:{prodid:prodid},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function (result) {
           $("#prod_desc").html(result.prod_desc);
                   
        },
        error:function (eobj, etxt, err) {
           console.log(etxt);
        }
     });
```

this is the division

```html
<div id='prod_desc'>
display all data as a list here
</div>
```

Comment: So `result.prod_desc` is a string with the value `"Camera :25MP | Memory :32GB | Battery: 3400mAh | Ram : 3GB"` and you would like to have it displayed as a list?

Comment: yes, I want display as a above list

Comment: then @Mirakurun's answer should already be what you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume from your question that your response is a string. We can use `data` as an example string variable.

Use `let dataArray = data.split("|")`. Then you will have an array with following values `["Camera :25MP", "Memory :32GB", "Battery: 3400mAh" ...]`

So `dataArray[0]` will be `"Camera :25MP"`, `dataArray[1]`  will be `"Memory: 32GB"` etc.